# Moving 2 sliders together

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am currently making a program for school where I have to lock the ratio while adjusting JSliders.

I could not figure out how to make one slider change with the same value while changing the first slider.
I want to change the sliders at a 1:1 ratio, so if I slide width up 5, the length will also go up 5, but I couldn't figure out how to find a constant difference to calculate when I change the value.

Comment: A "simple" solution would be to use the same model

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is it possible to have a constant variable that has the difference when the ratio is locked?

Comment: You could create one or two models which performed this operation for you, the problem is, when one reaches it's max/min state, you need to constrain the other

Comment: @MadProgrammer how can you create 2 sliders with same model?

Comment: Create a single `DefaultBoundedRangeModel` and apply it to both sliders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are setting length value based on `length.getValue`, but you want length to be set as width changes and vise versa. So I suggest that you set length like `length.setValue(width.getValue());`

```
 if(lkRatio.isSelected() !=true){
    tempw = width.getValue();
    templ = length.getValue();
    diff = width.getValue() - length.getValue();
}


if(lkRatio.isSelected()){

  if(source == width){
    length.setValue(width.getValue() - diff);
  }

  if(source == length){
       width.setValue(length.getValue() + diff);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you place a tick if you accept the answer pls.

Answer (score 2):

To answer "how can you create 2 sliders with same model" :

```
DefaultBoundedRangeModel brm = new DefaultBoundedRangeModel();
brm.setMaximum(100);
width = new JSlider(brm);
length = new JSlider(brm);
```